# Geometry pass through shader not displaying anything, however just using the frag and vert shader does display what i am drawing

Tags: c#, opengl, geometry, shader, opentk

This is the geometry shader i made, which from my understanding should simply pass the 3 vertices on to the frag shader? When i remove the geom shader and pass the values straight to the frag shader it works and displays what i want.
I am drawing terrain with triangles, each draw call passes 6 vertices (2 triangles) through, perhaps this has something to do with it however i cannot figure out what

```
#version 330

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3)out;


in float gHeight;
in vec4 gSurfacePosition;
in float gTerrainHeight;
in vec2 gTexCoords[3];
in vec4 gNormal[3];


out float oTerrainHeight;
out float oHeight;
out vec4 oNormal;
out vec4 oSurfacePosition;
out vec2 oTexCoords;


void main()
{

    oSurfacePosition=gSurfacePosition;
    oHeight=gHeight;
    oTerrainHeight=gTerrainHeight;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;

        oNormal = gNormal[i];
        oTexCoords = gTexCoords[i];

        EmitVertex();

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the compile errors? Because I'm fairly certain that GS can't compile. And it certainly can't actually do anything.

Comment: Yes it isn't meant to do ANYTHING it is just a pass through, yes it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> in float gHeight;
> in vec4 gSurfacePosition;
> in float gTerrainHeight;
> ```

This should not compile. Either you haven't checked for errors properly, or your implementation is really lax on reporting errors.

The reason this shouldn't compile is because all [GS inputs must be *arrayed*](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Inputs). You get one input value *per vertex* in the primitive. Your GS takes `triangles` as input, and therefore it gets each input value as an array of 3 values. You did this for some of the inputs, but you didn't do it for *all* of them.

> ```
> oSurfacePosition=gSurfacePosition;
> oHeight=gHeight;
> oTerrainHeight=gTerrainHeight;
> ```

This doesn't do what you think it does. Every time you call `EmitVertex`, the [value of all `out` variables becomes *undefined*](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Outputs). Therefore, every time you want to emit a new vertex, you *must* set the `out` variables again. Even if you want to write the same value, you have to set it each time.

Comment: Wow after reading that through i have realised how stupid that was of me, thanks for correcting that. Have only just started using GS today, thanks +1